# Structuring URI's for a multi-page signup form?

Tags: php, forms, rest

I'm building a website where users can sign up via a multi-step(page) form. The users entered data is carried from request to request (using sessions) and is not actually stored in my database until the final page of the form is completed.

I want to create my URI structure using a context that makes sense, so I thought about keeping it close to the HTTP RFC spec but it's easy to get lost in it's semantics. What is basically going on in my multi-page setup is I'm partly adding to a future resource in each request until the form is finally submitted (and the resource is saved). The resource cannot partly be saved, it would not make sense to have half a user in the database (fx. in case the user leaves the form halfway through).

So I thought about doing something like posting from `/signup?part=1` to `/signup?part=2` and so forth. But this kind of rubs me the wrong way, first of all I'm posting to a `signup` resource, which reallly doesn't make a whole lot of sense. And secondly I don't know if it makes sense to separate resource logic by a single GET parameter.

I could also do something like posting to `/signup/part1` which then displays a form that posts to `/signup/part2`. But that implies that the parts are subresources of the signup resource which doesn't make any sense.

Finally, I could go from `/signup-part1` to `/signup-part2`, but I don't know if this to big a separation of my signup logic.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Send all posts to `/signup` and distinguish the steps by a hidden `step` input field.

Comment: @arkascha In a general way, making the difference by a POST parameter will not allow you to continue where you left of if the process stops from various reasons (*like (but not limited to) browser crash*).

Answer (score 1):

If you are not building a REST API i'd say having different URLs for each step is fine as they represent different views.

`/signup-step1`, `/signup-step2` ...  `/signup-finished`

This also makes funnel tracking a lot easier, than passing the data in a hidden field.

It'll also play nicer with the browser history, if users would go back through steps.

Also for separation of logic you could route the URLs to different methods on the same controller, which would keep it in one place, but still separated in terms of handling the individual steps.

(just what did work for me in a couple of projects...)

If this was for a REST API i would keep it a single resource, handling the splitting client side.